# SQite - AUTO INCREMENT does not work

Tags: sql, datetime, sqlite

I've a table TABLE1 with my data. Another clean table TABLE2 as follow:

```
"TABLE2"(ipt TEXT,instant NUM, id integer auto_increment);
```

I want to select IP and instant in TABLE1 and insert it into TABLE2 but I don't know why the auto_increment doesn't work.

If someone has an idea.

Comment: Can you post sqlite query?

Comment: can you even create a table with auto_increment? afaik, it should be AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: "doesn't work" is to vague for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTOINCREMENT` can only be used in one situation. and that is for a column defined with a type/constraint of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

**`auto_increment`** is not a valid keyword and if you used `column id integer auto_increment` the result would be a column named **id** with a type of **integer auto_increment** which would then effectively be a column type of **INTEGER** i.e. the column's type affinity would be INTEGER. [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

i.e. you must have exactly `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. (case is irrelevant)

It can also only be coded once per table.

`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` with or without `AUTOINCREMENT` is a special case where the named column is made to be an alias of the **rowid** column. The **rowid** being a column that uniquely identifies the row, which is generally hidden (for want of a better description). **rowid** will not exists if the table is created with the `WITHOUT ROWID` keyword(s). In which case AUTOINCREMENT cannot be coded within a column definition.[Clustered Indexes and the WITHOUT ROWID Optimization](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)

Saying that it is almost certain that you do not in fact need to code `AUTOINCREMENT` just coding `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will very likely be sufficient and better for your needs. The column will still be given a unique identifier. an integer (64 bit signed) 1 for the first row inserted then likely 2, 3, 4 .....
- Note there is no guarantee that numbering will be sequential/monotonically increased.

Adding `AUTOINCREMENT` only ensures that the unique identifier is greater and in doing so imposes a limit that the identifier when reaching the highest possible value will subsequently result in an SQLITE_FULL exception, whilst without unused/free values (e.g. deleted rows) that are lower than the highest could be utilised.

To quote the SQLite documentation :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)